# Application Insights: receive email from alert only on failure

Tags: azure-application-insights

When I set up an alert in AI on metric "Server Exceptions" I also get emails notifying me of "Success". I don't want my inbox flooded with this type of messages. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At the bottom of the email there is an unsubscribe link. If you click that it will unsubscribe for this type of message.